# No response from url in Retrofit Parsing

Tags: android, parsing, retrofit

I am implementing the json parsing using retrofit but I didnot get any response from url. The Json data is in the form of Array inside which there are objects.I tried to set the response coming from Url in the TextView. I have implemented as follows:

My JSON structure is as follows:

```
[{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Nbn",
    "code": "001",
    "ecozone": "ter",
    "devregion": "east"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "hari",
    "code": "002",
    "ecozone": "hill",
    "devregion": "west"
}
]
```

Api Service

```
public interface ApiService {
@GET("/data_new.php?q=district")
Call<District> getMyJSON();
}
```

RetrofitClient

```
public class RetrofitClient {
private static final String url = "url/";

private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
public static ApiService getApiService(){
    return getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);
}
}
```

My ModelDto class

```
public class DistrictDTO {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
String code;

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

@SerializedName("ecozone")
@Expose
String ecozone;

public String getEcozone() {
    return ecozone;
}

public void setEcozone(String ecozone) {
    this.ecozone = ecozone;
}

@SerializedName("devregion")
@Expose
String devregion;

public String getDevregion() {
    return devregion;
}

public void setDevregion(String devregion) {
    this.devregion = devregion;
}


}
```

DistrictDTO

```
public class District {
public ArrayList<DistrictDTO> districtDTOS;

public ArrayList<DistrictDTO> getDistrictDTOS() {
    return districtDTOS;
}

public void setDistrictDTOS(ArrayList<DistrictDTO> districtDTOS) {
    this.districtDTOS = districtDTOS;
}
}
```

And Activity

```
public class DistrictActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<DistrictDTO> district;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_district);
    district = new ArrayList<>();
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textVi);
    ApiService api = RetrofitClient.getApiService();
    retrofit2.Call<District> call = api.getMyJSON();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<District>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<District> call, Response<District> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                //got successfully
                district = response.body().getDistrictDTOS();
                Log.e("Respose", "" + district);
                textView.setText(response.body().getDistrictDTOS().toString());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<District> call, Throwable t) {

            t.fillInStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: it should be array you taken an object as response  ...call for an array or list

Comment: can you please explain how to do that? @SantanuSur

Comment: In your `District` class change your `ArrayList<DistrictDTO>` to `List<DistrictDTO>`

Comment: Additional tip: you don't need `@SerializedName` if the class field is exactly named as the key ;)

Comment: @Nbn try to fetch array instead of object from your endpoint, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public interface ApiService {
@GET("/data_new.php?q=district")
Call<District[]> getMyJSON();
}
```

you are calling an array, not an object

Edit:

Actually, I think you should rename the class DistrictDTO to District, and delete the other one. And, change to `District[]` all the parts where you want that array

Answer (score 0):

Just make these changes it should work(**return array instead of object**)

```
 public class DistrictActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<DistrictDTO> district;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_district);
    district = new ArrayList<>();
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textVi);
    ApiService api = RetrofitClient.getApiService();
    retrofit2.Call<List<DistrictDTO>> call = api.getMyJSON();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DistrictDTO>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<List<DistrictDTO>> call, Response<List<DistrictDTO>> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                //got successfully
                district = response.body().toString();
                Log.e("Respose", "" + district);
                textView.setText(response.body().toString());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<List<DistrictDTO>> call, Throwable t) {
Toast.makeText(DistrictActivity.this,t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            t.fillInStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

}
```

and your interface should be like this

```
    public interface ApiService {
@GET("/data_new.php?q=district")
Call<List<DistrictDTO>> getMyJSON();
}
```

Infact you should expect an array instead of an object like above, just return a list of `DistrictDTO`, `District` class is not needed

FYI : when the response from server is of the form `{..}` you should expect an object(like you did) but when its like `[..]` its a json array and hence you should expect an array(this is your case, like i did in my answer)

Comment: can you please explain how to return a list of DistrictDTO ?

Comment: just change your retrofit's `call` return type as `<List<DistrictDTO>>` as mentioned above, change in both `Api Service` and your activity

Comment: @Nbn i have added an explanation on how to parse json in an `fyi` section in my answer

Comment: I have implemented as you directed but still the problem is same @fix

Comment: @Nbn add a toast in `onFailure` callabck like i have updated in my answer and check what is the error

Comment: @Nbn are you able to run the app(is it a `compile error`), if so try adding a break point inside your `onrespone` and `onfailure` callbacks and check if its getting called